# If someone uses Polyjuice potion on someone who has already used it, would they turn into the normal or "disguised" person?

Tags: harry-potter, polyjuice-potion

What would happen, if person A would take person B's hair and drink Polyjuice potion. Wait until transformation is complete and then take a hair from person A (as person B) and make person C drink Polyjuice potion.

Would person C turn into person A or person B and if it would be the first, wouldn't that be a method to determine whether or not someone has taken Polyjuice potion?

Comment: Hi hurricane_drunk. I closed this question as a duplicate of the linked question. If you feel that it's not you can [edit] your question to explain what you feel is not covered by the other one. Also related: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/188216/is-there-a-way-to-reveal-someone-using-polyjuice-potion